# How to get key to randomize like my values?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, random

I am writing code for a iOS quiz app and so far the code contains a dictionary that has the question as the key and the answers for that question as it values. My code randomizes an array of the keys (questions) and selects a key to be displayed at random. I also put the values (answers) in an array of values and randomized them as well and made sure that whatever index of of the array of questions is selected the same index of the array of answers is chosen.

However when I run the simulator the question label text remains the same and doesn't select a new index from the array of questions to be chosen as a new displayed question but on the other hand the array of answers to change after I select an answer.

Simply put, the question label text always stays the same and the title for the buttons (array of values) do select a different index. **How can I make it to where my question label changes and doesn't stay the same?**

Here is my code:

```
class QuestionDetails {
    let QADictionary = [
        "Who is Thor's brother?" : ["Atum", "Loki", "Red Norvell", "Kevin Masterson"],
        "What is the name of Thor's hammer?" : ["Mjolinr", "Uru", "Stormbreaker", "Thundara"],
        "Who is the father of Thor?" : ["Odin", "Sif", "Heimdall", "Balder"]
    ]

    //get question list
    func questionWithAnswers() {

        let listQuestions = QuestionDetails()

        var questionList = Array(listQuestions.QADictionary.keys)

        //random question index
        var rand = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questionList.count)))

        let randAnswers = rand

        //random answer index
        var answerList = Array(listQuestions.QADictionary.values)

        var choices = answerList[randAnswers]

        //fetch questions from list
        var question = questionList[rand]

        questionLabel.text = question

        //function for new question and button titles
        rightAnswerBox = arc4random_uniform(4)+1

        //create button
        var button:UIButton = UIButton()
        var x = 1

        for index in 1...4
        {
            button = view.viewWithTag(index) as! UIButton

            if (index == Int(rightAnswerBox))
            {
                button.setTitle(choices[0], for: .normal)
            }
            else {
                button.setTitle(choices[x], for: .normal)
                x += 1
            }

            randomImage()
        }
    }

    //variables
    var currentQuestion = 0
    var rightAnswerBox:UInt32 = 0
    var index = 0

    //Question Label
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!

    //Answer Button
    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        if (sender.tag == Int(rightAnswerBox)) {

            //removes asked question

            print ("Correct!")
        }
        else {
            wrongSeg()
            print ("Wrong!")
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        questionWithAnswers()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the dictionary's `keys`. Coerce to an array. Take the array's `count`. Generate a random number between 0 and `count` non-inclusive. Cast the random number down to an Int. Get the array element at that index. Use that as your key.

Test of the above approach:

```
extension ClosedRange where Bound : FloatingPoint {
    public func random() -> Bound {
        let range = self.upperBound - self.lowerBound
        let randomValue = (Bound(arc4random_uniform(UINT32_MAX)) / Bound(UINT32_MAX)) * range + self.lowerBound
        return randomValue
    }
}

let QADictionary = [
    "Who is Thor's brother?" : ["Atum", "Loki", "Red Norvell", "Kevin Masterson"],
    "What is the name of Thor's hammer?" : ["Mjolinr", "Uru", "Stormbreaker", "Thundara"],
    "Who is the father of Thor?" : ["Odin", "Sif", "Heimdall", "Balder"]
]
func test () {
    let questions = Array(QADictionary.keys)
    let r = (0...Double(questions.count)).random()
    let randomQuestion = questions[Int(r)]
    print(randomQuestion)
}
(1...40).forEach {_ in test()}
/*
Who is Thor's brother?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
Who is Thor's brother?
Who is the father of Thor?
Who is Thor's brother?
Who is Thor's brother?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
Who is Thor's brother?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
Who is Thor's brother?
Who is Thor's brother?
Who is the father of Thor?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
Who is the father of Thor?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
Who is the father of Thor?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
Who is the father of Thor?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
Who is Thor's brother?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
Who is Thor's brother?
Who is Thor's brother?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
Who is Thor's brother?
Who is Thor's brother?
Who is Thor's brother?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
Who is the father of Thor?
Who is Thor's brother?
Who is Thor's brother?
Who is Thor's brother?
Who is Thor's brother?
Who is Thor's brother?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?
What is the name of Thor's hammer?

*/
```